# How can I count numbers of a file and save consecutive orders?

Tags: bash, range

Assuming I have a file like this

```
1
2
3
5
8
9
```

I want to find out consecutive orders:

```
consecutive order from 1 to 3
consecutive order from 5 to 6
```

etc.

Comment: `5 to 6`? Did you mean `8 to 9` instead? Also, have you tried something so far?

Comment: Did you tried  `awk` comparing `$1` with a value stored at the previous line ?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call **/tmp/dataFile** fhe file containing your data, you can perform this with awk, like this:

```
awk 'NR==1{lowerBound=$1;upperBound=$1;next} $1 == upperBound+1 {upperBound=$1;next} {print "consecutive order from " lowerBound,"to", upperBound;lowerBound=$1;upperBound=lowerBound} END{print "consecutive order from " lowerBound,"to",upperBound}' /tmp/dataFile
```